# Value comparision in loop, best way to break loop when values are equal?

Tags: c#, multithreading, algorithm, loops

Take a hypothetical Aircraft class that has two properties; Altitude and AltitudeChange:

```
public class Aircraft  
{
    public double Altitude { get; set; }
    public AltitudeChange { get; set; }
}
```

And Altitude change has two properties; Altitude and RateOfClimb:

```
public class AltitudeChange
{ 
    public double Altitude { get; set; }
    public double RateOfClimb { get; set; } //Negative for descent
}
```

If we have a 'Worker Thread' that updates the Aircraft's altitude based on the time ellapsed and the Rate of Climb, what's the ideal design/implementation to ensure the loop stops when the new Altitude is hit?

```
private void AltitudeThreadWork()
{
    var updated = DateTime.Now;

    while (Aircraft.Altitude != AltitudeChange.Altitude)
    {
        UpdateAltitude((DateTime.Now - updated).TotalMilliseconds);
        updated = DateTime.Now;
        Thread.Sleep(40);
    }
}

private void UpdateAltitude(double ellapsed)
{
    Aircraft.Altitude += ellapsed*(AltitudeChange.RateOfClimb/60000d);
}
```

For example, this thread does't stop the climbing process because the double precision numbers are often not going to exactly equal each other.

Even if you cast the double to an int, you still can't be 100% sure that the two values will equal.

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem..

Comment: Realised I did that... was just going to

Comment: the problem here is that 9.999999999 can still be 9.9999999998 and thus not equal. Check if the difference between the two values is within a range and you'll be fine

Answer (score 2):

you can do it by looking for sign change:

```
private void AltitudeThreadWork()
{
    bool isOrigPositive = Aircraft.Altitude - AltitudeChange.Altitude > 0;

    do
    {
        var updated = DateTime.Now;
        UpdateAltitude((DateTime.Now - updated).TotalMilliseconds);
        Thread.Sleep(40);
        bool isNowPositive = Aircraft.Altitude - AltitudeChange.Altitude > 0;
    } 
    while (isOrigPositive == isNowPositive)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to make sure you don't overshoot. So instead of checking for equality, check whether applying the change would take you further *away* from the target altitude, or closer towards it.

You might *also* want to change the thread that adjusts the altitude to stop overshooting to start with. So for example, pseudocode:

```
double potentialAltitude = currentAltitude + AltitudeChange;
if (AltitudeChange < 0) // Going down... don't go below the "floor"
{
    newAltitude = Math.Max(potentialAltitude, TargetAltitude);
}
else // Going up... don't go above the "ceiling"
{
    newAltitude = Math.Min(potentialAltitude, TargetAltitude);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public bool AlttudeReached(double alt1, double alt2, double rateofClimb) {
        return rateofClimb > 0 ? alt1 >= alt2 : alt2 >= alt1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void AltitudeThreadWork()
{
    var updated = DateTime.Now;

    bool above = Aircraft.Altitude > AltitudeChange.Altitude;  // Determine if it is a climbing or a descent

    while ((Aircraft.Altitude > AltitudeChange.Altitude) == above)  // Check if it is in the same side of the plane defined by Altitude 
    // (because altitude is a continuous function, if it is on the other "side" it means it has crossed the given altitude)
    {
        UpdateAltitude((DateTime.Now - updated).TotalMilliseconds);
        updated = DateTime.Now;
        Thread.Sleep(40);
    }

    Aircraft.Altitude = AltitudeChange.Altitude;  // Altitude is reached
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with floats/doubles is that checking for equality is hard. Therefor you should use a 'range' in which you consider them "equal".

Covering both up and down in 1 line:

```
while(Math.Abs(Altitude - AltitudeChange.Altitude) > 0.0001)
```

Comment: It not only a matter of double precision because the altitude is increasing (or decreasing) by step. I assume this step can be between 0.01 and 10 (given the situation).

Comment: Two values are exactly equal if A-B=0. Since: 2-2=0, that holds true. The problem here is that 9.99999 - 9.99998 = 0.00001, and while they might be 'equal enough', they are not equal according to the comparison. You just have to pick the range correctly. 1000.0001 might be considered equal to 1000.0000, but 0.000199999 is way different from 0.00029999. It's all in the significance of the numbers